# Drupal can't create new users, error 101 or 324

Tags: php, mysql, drupal

So I have been trying to add users and tried some of the solutions I have found out and about on the net, so far I have come out empty handed.

My issue is as follows, I seem to be able to modify and edit any and all settings that has to do with the database, except users. Every time I try to make a new user, I get either a 101 (Connection reset) or 324 (Connection Timeout) error.

I have tried adding longer timeouts with htaccess, I have tried moving databases, hell I even took a look at some caching settings.

So I am really in no mans land here, and hoping you can help me out. :)

Update:
Increasing max_allowed_packet did not work.

Update 2:
When I try to make a new user the first time, it makes a 101 using the exact same data after that will always generate a 324.

Comment: can you connect to your mySQL database via the `mysql` commandline tool and submit an `INSERT` from there?

Comment: How are you trying to create new users? Are you using the user_save() function?

Comment: As said, all Inserts work fine, and I just tested to make sure, it even works on the user table if I do it manually.
I am using the interfaces "+add user" functionality to try and add users.

Comment: How big is your MySQL max_allowed_packet var?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be somehow a settings related problem with the MySQL server, but with a webhosting company unwilling to help or assist me in error finding, I must conclude that I cannot locate the error.
So if you should run into the same issue and the max_allowed_packet fix does not work for you, I suggest you either find a webhosting company that knows what they are doing or set up a server yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Connection Timeout and Connection reset are almost always caused by max_allowed_packet being to small. 
I keep my Drupal sites around 16M. This is set in my.cnf.
1048576 is equal to 1M which is the default setting and is not enough for Drupal.

Comment: Yeah that is true, minor miscalculation on my part. I have a little problem in that it is a rented server and I do not have access to the configuration file of mysql, nor do I have super privileges to turn it on permanently, so I am unable to test the suggestion. :(

Comment: I used a shared server for a while and they had a back-end interface that let me set a custom my.cnf file. Then you drop your own my.cnf into your home directory so it can override the default. I think that's pretty much your best bet if you can't get another server.

Comment: The problem is that it is a shared service, so if people could muck around with the settings, it would be complete chaos.
I did however ask my supplier if they could put up the packet size, and they did, but the problem is still there.